# MongoDB duplicate error while creating document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using MERN stack to develop web application. I created a controller to create a document namely "UserServiceProfile" with a nested array of "serviceCategory" documents in it. However, after creating the first document of UserServiceProfile, subsequence creation throws "duplicate error" with the following message:

```
 {
    "msg": "Duplicate value found for .\n        Please choose another value.\n        "
}
```

The embedding document schema is:

```
 const UserServiceProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountType: {
        type: String,
        enum: {
            values: ['service man', 'service consumer', 'business'],
            message: '{VALUE} is not supported'
        },
        default: 'service consumer'
    },
    services: {
        type: [ServiceCategorySchema],
        message: 'Service is not supported'
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [true, 'Please provide user'],
        ref: 'User'
    }, 
})

const UserProfileModel = mongoose.model('profile', UserProfileSchema)
const UserServiceProfileModel = mongoose.model('userServiceProfile', UserServiceProfileSchema)
```

The embedded document schema:

```
const ServiceCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide service name'],
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 30,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 200,
        required: [true, 'Please provide service description']
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})

const ServiceCategoryModel = mongoose.model('serviceCategory', ServiceCategorySchema)
```

The controller where the document is created is:

```
const createUserServiceProfile = async(req, res) =>{ 
    const {accountType, service} = req.body
    const {userID} = req.user

    if( !accountType){
        throw new BadRequestError('Please provide account type')
    }
    if(!service){
        throw new BadRequestError('Please provide service')
    }

    // check if service profile exist
    const existingServiceProfile = await UserServiceProfileModel.findOne({user: userID})
    
    if(existingServiceProfile){
        throw new BadRequestError("Profile created already")
    }
    console.log(userID)
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({_id: userID})
    if(!user){
        throw new UnAuthenticatedError(`User with ID ${userID} not found`)
    }

    const newService = {
        name: service.name,
        _id: service._id,
        description: service.description,
        active: service.active
    }

    const userServiceProfile = await UserServiceProfileModel.create(
            {
                accountType, 
                services: [newService], 
                user: userID
            }
        )

    res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json(
        {
            success: true, 
            msg: 'User service profile created', 
            userServiceProfile
        }
    )
}
```

Thank you as you take your precious time to assist.

Comment: Did you define any unique index in the mongo collection?

Comment: Please add to your question an example of how you use this so it create the error

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes I did but I later remove that property

Comment: @RafaelJan The error message I stated in the question comes from Postman.

Comment: Check if the unique index still exists in the collection itself.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Thanks so much. I deleted the indexes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Although you removed the unique index from code, it still exists in the collection itself. You should remove the unique index from the collection.